How is gcc's malloc attribute used?
I'm not really sure I understand gcc's malloc attribute correctly.
For example, take a look at this program:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

__attribute__((returns_nonnull, malloc, malloc(free, 1)))
void *safe_malloc(size_t n)
{
    void *memory = malloc(n);
    if (memory == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed: malloc(%zu)\n", n);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return memory;
}

typedef struct
{
    size_t n, capacity;
    int *elements;
} array_list;

__attribute__((nonnull))
void free_array_list(array_list *lst)
{
    if (lst->elements != NULL)
    {
        free(lst->elements);
    }
    free(lst);
}


__attribute__((returns_nonnull, malloc, malloc(free_array_list, 1)))
array_list *new_array_list()
{
    array_list *lst = safe_malloc(sizeof(array_list));
    lst->elements = NULL;
    lst->capacity = 0;
    lst->n = 0;

    return lst;
}

int main(void)
{
    array_list *lst = new_array_list();
    free_array_list(lst);
    
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

The way I understood __attribute__((..., malloc, malloc(free_array_list, 1))) was that

malloc meant, that new_array_list returns new memory similar to malloc, and
malloc(free_array_list, 1) meant, that the memory returned by new_array_list should be released by free_array_list.

So kind of similar to an initializer and destructor, new_array_list returns something that should later be cleaned up by free_array_list.
But if you compile this piece of code with -fanalyzer (I've tried gcc version 11.3.0 and 12.3.0) the warning indicates that the memory allocated in new_array_list by safe_malloc is leaked.
What am I getting wrong?

Note that test if (lst->elements != NULL) not needed for free(lst->elements);, yet if (lst != NULL) is useful before free(lst->elements); to avoid UB if lst == NULL.

@chux-ReinstateMonica Good point, not sure why I put that there
Interestingly, clangd actually flags if (lst != NULL) due to __attribute__((nonnull)).

The info page says "To indicate that an allocation function both satisifies the nonaliasing property and has a deallocator associated with it, both the plain form of the attribute and the one with the DEALLOCATOR argument must be used."

I manually inlined safe_malloc() to simplify the code but get strange warnings: leak of lst, use after free_array_list of lst, and lst should have been deallocated with free but was deallocated with free_array_list.  The latter suggest that gcc is not grok'ing malloc (free_array_list, 1).   cpp tells me that (stdlib) malloc() has the attributes __attribute__ ((__nothrow__ , __leaf__)) __attribute__ ((__malloc__)) __attribute__ ((__alloc_size__ (1))) perhaps no dealloc due to realloc()?

https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=105530

https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=98992 suggest a regression of the malloc attribute with a deallocator specified.
